# Why Future works after the main function was done?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

In the [example on dart.dev](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#example-introducing-futures) the Future prints the message after the main function was done.

Why might the Future work after the main function was done? At first glance, after the completion of the main function, the entire work of the program is expected to be completed (and the Future must be cancelled).

The example code:

```
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() {
  // Imagine that this function is fetching user info from another service or database.
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('Large Latte'));
}

void main() {
  fetchUserOrder();
  print('Fetching user order...');
}
```

The program prints

```
Fetching user order...
Large Latte
```

I've expected just the following

```
Fetching user order...
```

Comment: Because the presence of the Future keeps the event loop going? Isn't that sort of the point?

Comment: I don't know if it's still explicitly explained anywhere, but an [old article from the Dart website](https://web.archive.org/web/20190510212408/https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await) discusses this: "When `main()` has finished executing, the asynchronous functions can resume execution..."

Comment: If you really want to exit the program I guess you should use `exit(0)` from `dart:io` which wont wait for any future to complete and just quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the nature of futures and asynchronous programming. Behind the scenes, Dart manages something called the asynchronous queue. When you initiate a future (either manually like you did with `Future.delayed` or implicitly by calling a method marked `async`, that function's execution goes into the queue whenever its execution gets deferred. Every cycle when Dart's main thread is idle, it checks the futures in the queue to see if any of them are no longer blocked, and if so, it resumes their execution.

A Dart program will not terminate while futures are in the queue. It will wait for all of them to either complete or error out.